# How are metrics computed in Keras?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I am wondering how does Keras compute a metric (a custom one or not).

For example, suppose I have the following metric which yields the maximal error between the prediction and the ground truth:

```
def max_error(y_true, y_pred):

    import keras.backend as K

    return K.max(K.abs(y_true-y_pred))
```

Is the output scalar metric computed on all mini-batches and then averaged or is the metric directly computed on the whole dataset (training or validation)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Something additional to know with respect to the metric for the VALIDATION set:**

Contrary to what is suggested in another answer, I just saw that the metric on the **validation set is calculated in batches**, and then averaged (of course the trained model at the end of the epoch is used, in contrast to how the metric score is calculated for the training set).

If you want to compute it on the whole validation data at once, you have to use a callback as described in the <s>accepted</s> answer of guangshengzuo (see https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/  for more details).

Sure, for the usual metrics, there will not be any difference whether you calculate first in batches and average, or do it all in one big batch. BUT for custom metrics, there very well can be: I just had a case where the metric would tune a parameter, based on the data.

Edit: added link on callbacks, in response to comment

Comment: Do you have by any chance an example code for this custom callback (since you have become the accepted answer)?

Comment: Also, in the case of a custom callback metric, is there a way to add it to Tensorboard?

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between the metric on training dataset and on validation dataset. For the val set the metric is calculated at epoch end for your whole val dataset.
For the train set: The metric is calculated on batch end and the average keeps getting updated till epochs end.

As you can see the metric for the train set is evaluated on the fly with each batch was evaluated using different weights. That's why the train metric shows sometimes strange behaviour.

Comment: Ok, indeed for some metrics, averaging over mini-batches does not make sense, as it is the case for my `max_error' metric`. I have thus added my metrics to `stateful_metrics` in the `BaseLogger` to accumulate the metrics over mini-batches.

Comment: Actually it's never a good idea: Imagine fist epoch and your model is not trained at all. Then after the first batch you evaluate something on a barely trained model. This will be averaged with all the other batches. This includes batches at the end of the epoch, which already uses a much better model. You can see the metric for the train dataset as a on the fly metric which you shouldn't take very seriously. I always recommend to write your own custom callback, in which you calculate and print your desired metrics yourself. That way you're sure what's happening.

Comment: I understand, but as my model converges, the phenomenom you describe will have its influence neglectible no? But I agree that the validation metrics are the most interesting values to monitor to check my model performances.

Comment: Yep you're right. So if it doesn't bother you, you're good to go

Comment: Are you sure that the metric is computed on the whole validation dataset and not averaged? Because when I use the `evaluate()` function the metrics values depend on the `batch_size` argument.

Comment: I looked in the source code a bit. It seems like keras is using the same batch_size for evaluation as for fitting. This makes sense, because otherwise it would risk an Ressource error. The validation dataset is still evaluated on epochs end. Sorry I didn't realize that the fact of usage of batches for evaluation is that important for your metric. I guess now the best option would be to write your own Callback for evaluation.

Comment: My `max` metric on the validation dataset seems indeed to be averaged on batches which does not make sense. Otherwise, the batch_size would have no effect on the evaluate function.

Answer (score 3):

Dennis has already explain this clearly.

One more thing to point out, if you want compute the metric over all train datasets, Or like your custome metric function could just be computed on single pass and no averaging, you could try ***use the keras callback and define the on_epoch_end, in on_epoch_end method you could compute this on whole train data.***

like this :

```
 def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
     y_pred = self.model.predict(self.X_train, verbose=0)
     score = max_error(self.y_train, y_pred)
     y_val_pred = self.model.predict(self.X_val, verbose=0)
     val_score = max_error(self.y_val, y_val_pred)
     print("\n ROC-AUC - epoch: %d - train score: %.6f \n - val score: %.6f" % (epoch+1, score, val_score))
```

And you need **pass the train data and val data to model.fit's validation_data parameter**.

Comment: That's what I've done using `self.model.evaluate` within `on_epoch_end`

Comment: if you do as code above, then the metric is evaluate on all train datas

Comment: using `batch_size=self.y_val.size` in `evaluate` works too. Thanks